# Como colocar no Route um parametro object

Tags: c#

Estou criando um metodo para enviar push notification do firebase.

Tem 3 informações que preciso passar, são elas: `string title`, `string body` e `object data`

Quando comecei a fazer, fiz assim `[Route("controller/{title}/{body}")]` e por falha minha, esqueci de colocar o `object data` no Route também. E foi ai que surgiu a minha duvida.

> Como eu faço para colocar no Route um parametro do tipo `object`?

Método:

`public async void EnviarPushNotification(string title, string body, object data) { ... }`

Exemplo Data:

```
data: {
   action: "Play",
   playerId: 5
}
```

Edit

[Neste link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), mostra que há um payload com o `data`, mas não mostra as opções que podem ser usadas nele

[Neste outro link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages?hl=pt-br), mostra varios `key: value`, mas não sobre o `data`

---

Consegui entender o que são os itens possiveis do `data`, são personalizados que eu posso criar no meu console do firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: seria melhor se recebesse  o data por request se fir um POST para o endpoint, mas não pode tipar esse object? criar uma classe para eles, faria o post e parse muito mais simples ;)

Comment: então, eu pensei nisso, porem eu não encontrei quais são todas as possibilidades que podem ir dentro do data ainda, no exemplo que coloquei acima eu citei o `action` e o `playerId`, mas acredito que não são somente eles... Estou procurando ainda quais keys ele aceita... Por isso queria saber se tem outra forma de fazer que não seja pelo POST e criar um classe e tal... Porque ai eu não preciso fixar os dados nele

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloquei uns edites na publicação da duvida e entendi quais sao os key value, que na realidade sou eu quem crio mesmo... Obrigado pela ajuda